# Calculate automatically scaled font size in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I use UILabel with NSAttributedString and I have these settings for my label

```
label.numberOfLines = 4
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingMiddle
```

Then I call

```
label.sizeToFit()
```

I always get the size for the full size font, so my text will be aligned horizontally center. So if the normal line height is 32, my 4 lines will have 128 in height. However my text will be scaled to 0.5, so the actual text height is about 64, which leaves much upper and lower spaces.

Is there anyway I can calculate the actual size of the label after it is scaled.

I test my app with iPhone 6 + iOS 8.1.1

Comment: Try func boundingRectWithSize(_ size: CGSize,
                  options options: NSStringDrawingOptions,
               attributes attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
                  context context: NSStringDrawingContext!) -> CGRect

Comment: @Andy I tried that and it ignores the minimumScaleFactor also.